# How to import all vs symbols into Source Insight?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, source-insight

Just switched to Source Insight,how to import all symbols(library and header files) that are available in visual studio into Source Insight?

Comment: 64 questions, 0 answers, 0 votes, 35% accept.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't the wizard prompt you to do this when you started it the first time?

If not, you can create a new project and add all the relevant files to it. Then rebuild the project from scratch and save it.

You can then add that project to your real project in tools->preferences->project symbol path